# Rudin's Construction of Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

At the end of chapter 1 of Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Rudin provides a proof of the construction of real numbers. The first step in the proof is to define members of $\mathbb{R}$ that are subsets of $\mathbb {Q}$ known as **cuts**. Rudin gives the following definition of a cut:

1. $\alpha$ is not empty, and $\alpha \neq \mathbb{Q}$.
2. If $p \in \alpha, q \in \mathbb {Q}$, and $q < p$, then $ q \in \alpha$
3. If $p \in \alpha$, then $p < r$ for some $r \in \alpha$.

The letters $p, q, r, \ldots$ will always denote rational numbers, and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \ldots$ will denote cuts.

My question is the following:
**Doesn't the definition of the cut provided lead to the conclusion that each cut contains all rational numbers?**

In other words, that $\alpha = \mathbb {Q}$ for all $\alpha$?

The third property of cuts provided shows that there is no maximal element in a cut. The second property implies that given an element in a cut, all rational numbers less than that element are in the cut. Doesn't this clearly imply that cuts include all the rationals?

I was hoping someone could clear this up. Thanks.

Comment: The set of all strictly negative rationals ought to be a cut, and it _doesn't_ equal $\mathbb Q$. How do you think it fails to satisfy the definition?

Comment: Not every linear ordering shares the property of $\mathbb{N}$ that every nonempty subset with no greatest element is unbounded.

Comment: @user1709828: It's clearly relevant and appropriate to tell the asker that this construction in generally credited to Dedekind (under the particular name "Dedekind cuts"). What made your initial comment sound off was that it looked like the OP was in error for not _already_ knowing this.

Comment: One way to read (3) is: "There is no strict maximum element of a cut."

Comment: I think you just have to realize that a nonempty set of numbers can be bounded above and still have no maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course not. For example, the set of negative rational numbers are a cut.

Comment: But it appears to me that this is not a cut according to the three properties given to me in the question. For example, if $p = 0$ in the third property, there is no rational number $r$ that is greater than $p$ and within the set of negative rational numbers.

Comment: $p=0$ is not a negative rational number, @user60994

Comment: @user60994: $0$ is not a negative number, so it is not in Chris’s cut.

Comment: Chris, that should be "is a cut." A set is singular, it is not "are a cut."

Comment: Ah I see now... That should have been obvious. Thank you!

Comment: @Thomas: ‘England are all out for 243.’ :-)

Comment: @user60994: If that cleared up your confusion, please mark Chris' answer as "accepted" by clicking on the outlined green checkmark on the left of it. Then other users of the site will know there's nothing more to do here.

Comment: @Thomas: This is a minor dialectical difference in English. "Are" is correct in my dialect.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That's not a sport idiom that I have read before, but sports makes for bad examples. In the states, most team names are plural, so you mights write "The Cubs are pitching badly," but write "The team is pitching badly."  As a rule, does the sentence "The set are a cut" read like English? My teachers always said to eliminate auxiliarly phrases to find the correct plural/singular choice.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Can I ask where you are? Just curious.

Comment: England.${}{}{}$

Comment: @Thomas: It’s not just a sport idiom: it’s standard British English. A collective noun can by used with a plural verb when the emphasis is more on the multiple individuals than on the group as a single entity. E.g., *the government are determined to follow this course*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, here in the US, sport teams are the most common oddity in our rules. "The Cubs are..." versus "The team is..." Here, it feels really unclear to use "are" because you are talking about a property of the set, rather than properties of the elements, but that's probably just my American language expectations.

Comment: Just curious, would the English ever write, after defining a set $S$, "$S$ are a cut?" Or, "The set $S$ are a cut?" @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Thomas: No, it’s the *of negative rational numbers* that licences the plural verb in Chris’s sentence. (Note: I’m not a native speaker of BrE, so I’m not reliable on borderline cases, but this isn’t one.)

Comment: That was my guess, @BrianM.Scott. It goes against all my language training, because we are taught to match verb to the primary noun, essentially trained to ask, "What would you say without the 'of ...' clause."

Comment: Sports journalists use "the team are ..." to make their writing more vivid—conveying the idea of the physical individuals who make up the team (which is a more abstract concept). This usage is a poor model for mathematical writing, where the distinction between a (singular) set and its (plural) elements is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: A *cut* is a set of the form:
$$\mathbb Q\cap (-\infty,r)$$
where $r$ is any **real** number.

The reason they haven't been defined this way, is because you haven't defined the real numbers yet.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I thought this too when I was learning about cuts.

It actually seems reasonable: if there is no largest element, and all the rational numbers less than an element in the cut are included, then the cut should contain all rational numbers.

The thing is, the definition doesn't define how the numbers get larger. Rather, it just says that there is no largest member.

Then, we could pick any open interval and change it so that it matches the conditions. For example, if I had the open interval from 0 to 1, then you can see that this interval has no largest element. That's the idea, that cuts are just open intervals with some special properties.

At least, that's how I think of it.